# How to connect a PC with an RS323C interface?

Tags: java, c#, python, serial-port, usb

I want to control a circulator (Thermo Haake DC30/DL30) which has got a RS232c interface. My first problem is that my computer has got only USB connections. Is it possible to use a RS323 to USB adapter and transmit commands and which libraries could you recommend me to use?

Also I don't know which language would be recommended. I am experienced in C# and Java. But I wanted to try out Python. I heard that it is less code to write and it would be a great opportunity to learn Python at the same time.

At the end I want a GUI in which I can set values like temperature, interval, read the current temperature or any fault messages.

Answer (score 2):

I think what a USB to COM adapter does is create a virtual COM-Port on your PC, which you can then use like a regular one. Just make sure to get the right drivers, if you even need them.

I wrote a small app that required barcode scanners via RS232 in Python and I think I used [PySerial](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/), it is also definitely possible with C#, I tried that but gave up, since the application was no longer needed.

Comment: Alternatively, you could get a COM-server, which takes the RS232 signal and makes it available via Ethernet. They are a little expensive but also have their use cases.

Comment: I cannot use Ethernet, because this port is already used for LAN.
I will try to use PySerial, thanks.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, you would connect your circulator to the COM-Server and then connect it to your network. Nothing would be plugged into your PC.